# Change color of text in GTK 3.0

Tags: python, gtk, gtk3

I am using a `Gtk.TextBuffer()` inside a `Gtk.TextView()` to write some text on the screen. I wish to change colors of the text while writing often. eg.

```
In Green -- Printing Green color
In Red   -- Printing Red color
In Green -- Printing Green color
In Red   -- Printing Red color
```

Can you please suggest some function to do this.

Comment: There is no such thing as PyGtk3. pygtk is gtk2 and obsolete.

Answer (score 1):

To specify that some text in the buffer should have specific formatting, you must define a tag to hold that formatting information, and then apply that tag to the region of text using `create_tag("tag name", property)` and `apply_tag(tag, start_iter, end_iter)` as in, for instance:

```
tag = textbuffer.create_tag("orange_bg", background="orange")
textbuffer.apply_tag(tag, start_iter, end_iter)
```

The following are some of the common styles applied to text:

- Background colour ("background" property)
- Foreground colour ("foreground" property)
- Underline ("underline" property)
- Bold ("weight" property)
- Italics ("style" property)
- Strikethrough ("strikethrough" property)
- Justification ("justification" property)
- Size ("size" and "size-points" properties)
- Text wrapping ("wrap-mode" property)

You can also delete particular tags later using `remove_tag()` or delete all tags in a given region by calling `remove_all_tags()`.

Answer (score 0):

Since GTK3.16 you can use pango markup.

```
self.textbuffer.insert_markup(iter, markup);
```

.

```
self.textbuffer.insert_markup(self.textbuffer.get_end_iter(), "<b>and some bold text</b>", -1)
```

[StackOverflow answer with example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41452162/using-markup-with-gtk-textview)

GTK3+ doc:
https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkTextBuffer.html#gtk-text-buffer-insert-markup

> Inserts the text in markup at position iter . markup will be inserted
>   in its entirety and must be nul-terminated and valid UTF-8. Emits the
>   “insert-text” signal, possibly multiple times; insertion actually
>   occurs in the default handler for the signal. iter will point to the
>   end of the inserted text on return.